# If $f \circ \cdots \circ f (z) = g (z)$ for endomorphisms on a Riemann surface, what can be said about $g$ given the existence of such an $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Supposing that $f \circ \cdots \circ f (z) = g (z)$ for endomorphisms on a Riemann surface, what are some generalities we can conclude about $g$ given the existence of such an $f$?

I am mostly interested in the case for $\mathbb{C}$.